# Margins between li's out of nowhere

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

So, i am creating a menu, and i noticed that there is some unexplainable margin between li's. It also can not be seen in dev's console. Here is the code:
**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
                <ul class="navbar_ul">
                    <li class="navbar_list_item navbar_main">Point Blank</li>
                    <li class="navbar_list_item navbar_main">Tanki Online</li>
                    <li class="navbar_list_item navbar_main">Dota 2</li>
                    <li class="navbar_list_item navbar_main">Warface</li>
                    <li class="navbar_list_item navbar_minor">Топ аккаунтов</li>
                    <li class="navbar_list_item navbar_minor navbar_last_item">О нас</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And, here is the **CSS**:

```
.navbar_list_item {
        display: inline-block;
        }
.navbar, .navbar ul, .navbar li {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        }

    .navbar_ul {
        width: 100%;
        }

    .navbar_list_item {
        color: white;
        width: 16.3%;
        margin: 0;
        height: 40px;
        }

    .navbar_main {
        background-color: #3978C2;
        }

    .navbar_minor {
        background-color: #2E3A86;
        }
```

Here is the screenshot of menu:
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: I mean those white spaces between li's, as seen on image above

Comment: This doesn't appear to be all the CSS, please make a reproducible example.

Comment: Ok i see them thanks i will see what i can do

Comment: Nope, nothing changes

Comment: That is not full code..

Comment: Okay, you see [it's not the full code](https://jsfiddle.net/qx2h8jo8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the space/new line characters between `</li>` and `<li>` tags. Try to write the markup as such:

```
<li>content</li><li>content</li><
li>another content</li><li>yet another one</li>
```

Comment: While this answer is absolutely a correct one, I personally dislike this method of fixing inline-block elements. Plenty of people use it, but I find it hard to read, hard to maintain, and it kind of side steps the separation of responsibilities that HTML/CSS have worked so hard for the last few generations.  Again, it's not wrong it's just not my favorite.

Comment: I agree, but it seems there's no elegant solution to that. Negative margins are a hack too.

Answer (score 1):

The space is there is a 'side effect' (actually confusing but intended behavior) of how `display: inline-block` works.  Inline block elements are rendered the same as inline elements, namely it assumes that they should be part of a line of text. Add to that the fact that HTML compresses all whitespace (space, tab, newline) into a single space and what happens is **the newline character between each LI becomes a space character and you have a small visible gap between elements.**

There are several methods to fight this. You might

- Use negative margins to bump the elements back in line
- Use zero-sized font
- Use `display: block` and `float: left`
- Use `display: table`
- Remove all whitespace characters between LIs in your code

And there are other methods. Each has its own advantages and disadvantages.

A nice writeup of different solutions can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

There are no margin between li element. the space between each li is related to your

```
   width: 16.3%;
```

so you have 6 li element proportionally spaced ..

This mean that for each element the width is fixed..

Comment: In the image of the menu you posted i don't see space between li but 6 menu voice with a proportional width of 16,3%. no spaces..